# How to check if array has values from another array in Javascript in one line?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `items` which contains a list of strings which I want to search against me `key_res` array which contains some keywords I need either a true or false value on.

This is the code I have so far which works:

```
const items = ['Quality 1080p', 'Quality 720p', 'Quality 4K'];
const key_res = ['4K', '6K'];
contains_string = items.every(item => {
            if(key_res.some(string => item.includes(string))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Is there a way I can return a boolean value easier than going through a loop and then setting a boolean?

Comment: u need looping anyway

Comment: `items.some(i => key_res.some(k => i.includes(k)))`

Comment: thats a one line solution you have there already, made in different lines for better formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `some` instead of `forEach`:

```js
let items = ['Quality 1080p', 'Quality 720p', 'Quality 4K'];
const key_res = ['4K', '6K'];
let bool = items.some(item => key_res.some(string => item.includes(string)));
console.log(bool);

items = ['Quality 1080p', 'Quality 720p'];
bool = items.some(item => key_res.some(string => item.includes(string)));
console.log(bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, it really doesn't save a lot of code, but using `map` instead of `forEach` will loop and allow you to return a value.  So now you only `console.log` one time

```js
const items = ['Quality 1080p', 'Quality 720p', 'Quality 4K'];
const key_res = ['4K', '6K'];
console.log(items.map(i => key_res.some(s => i.includes(s))));
```

Comment: careful for OPs edits, they seem to change the context to the point where your answer no longer makes as much sense as it did before

Comment: Ah geez, yeah OP's code in the question is totally different now than when I posted this!